# executing a parsed script/snippet inside a c++ application

Tags: python, c++, interpreted-language

We have a large codebase in c++ and some .NET. Visual studio 2010.

A main part of the application is a node graph based around the actor model. The nodes are state machines and turn booleans and numeric inputs into boolean and numeric outputs, which may be connected to the input of another node and so on.

The system comprise many types of nodes with various configuration options.

A customer has asked for a rather complex and flexible set of node types, some of which may not be completely clarified until the system is in production. I hope to implement this entire thing by creating a new node type which accepts a python (or similar) text as its configuration.

Python was suggested by the stakeholder, but not necessarily the only option. What options exist to parse and execute another high level language inside a c++ code base in a VBA-like fashion?

Comment: Actually this question is more or less a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150442/scripting-language-for-c

Answer (score 1):

You have quite some options here:

Lua (http://www.lua.org/)

Python (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I)

An alternative to python: Pypy(http://pypy.org/)

Comment: That looks promising. I will take a look at it.